# Formata direito com header mas não com include

Tags: php, html, css

Com header

```
 header( 'Location:conteudo/agenda.php');
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
   Ao clicar no dia 14
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com include

```
 include 'conteudo/agenda.php';
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Não acontece nada ao clicar

Eu pretendia fazer com include

Comment: No primeiro exemplo, você está redirecionando o usuário para o location informado, e no segundo incluindo algo. São coisas totalmente distintas. Não dá pra ajudar sem ver o código, mas acredito que o problema esteja nos arquivos de assets do front (CSS e/ou JS) que não puderam ser encontrados no segundo exemplo. Dê um CTRL + U, clique nos links dos assets e veja se estão acessíveis.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173740/what-is-difference-between-header-and-include-where-which-one-should-be-used

Comment: Muito provavelmente seus arquivos de JS estão em conflito, o fato de funcionar com o "header", é que ele redireciona para uma página totalmente nova, já no "include ", você coloca basicamente uma página dentro da outra, chama uma em outra. E nessa sua chamada, você deve ter algum arquivo JS, sendo executado nas duas, o que te gera um conflito e ele trava.

Comment: Tente retirar todos os arquivos chamados em agenda.php e chama-los em sua página principal somente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi o problema colocando o conteúdo dentro de um iframe.